# How Values are assigned in Anonymous function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand whether 15 is sent to x or n

```
def func_compute(n):
    return lambda x : x * n
result = func_compute(2)
print("Double the number of 15 =", result(15))
```

Comment: `func_compute(2)` returns a function, the anonymous lambda function. `result(15)` calls that anonymous function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.How 15 is assigned to x?

Comment: Can you clarify *what exactly* you do not understand about this? Do you understand what ``x`` and ``n`` in ``return lambda x : x * n`` are? Do you understand what ``func_compute(2)`` evaluates to? Do you see how ``x * n``  evaluates to 30, given that a function taking ``n`` was fed ``2`` and a function taking ``x`` was fed ``15``?

Comment: You explicitly pass it as a parameter: `result(15)`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you for offering help, Actually I don't understand  how fun_compute(2) evaluates, we didn't send the 15, I mean how 15 is assigned to n

Comment: why my question got negative evaluation, I mentioned in my question that I was new to programming

Comment: @Yusufahmad 15 is not sent to n, it is sent to x. Why do you think it is sent to n? What value do you think is sent to x?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think 2 is sent to x and 15 is sent to n

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, could you please elaborate it further ? you're replies are helpful

Answer (score 2):

Assume a function f(x, n) = x*n. Now you want to have this function for a fixed n, i.e., f_n(x) = x*n. This is what func_compute(n) does, it returns f_n(x), a function, for the given n.

result(15) is then f_2(15) = f(15, 2) = 30.